# Merge multiple Access database into one big database with c# code

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I have multiple Access 2007 databases (accdb files) that are identical and i want to merge them into one using windows form using c# code but i don't know how to do it because i'm a beginner in c#
database are identical but i want to keep all data into one because all datatables have only one or two rows because i use access form for questionnaires from differnt students in my university and they sent me their answers so i must open all files one by one and i want to greate a windows form application because i am going to take some results from the answers.

Comment: It the databases are identical, then why do you need to merge them?

Comment: database are identical but i want to keep all data into one because all datatables have only one or two rows because i use access form for questionnaires from differnt students in my university and they sent me their answers so i must open all files one by one and i want to greate a windows form application because i am going to take some results from the answers.

Comment: (1) How many database files are we talking about? (2) How many tables are in each file?

Comment: 100+ database files with one table in each file

Comment: This can be done almost as easily with an Access UI, if you feel more comfortable using Access.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take the following steps:

1. Create a database with a single table to hold the final results. The table should have the exact same structure as the individual files, but with a primary key field - either the path to the database file, or some other unique value for each row (this can be generated with an AutoNumber field). You may want an additional column for the database path in any case, particularly if you need to prevent rereading the same database file multiple times.
2. Open an ADO.NET connection to the final database, using the OleDb provider. This entails a) creating an `OleDbConnection` object, b) creating an `OleDbCommand` object that runs on the connection, c) setting the `CommandText` of the command object to an SQL statement, and d) executing the command.
3. Your SQL statement could look something like this:

   ```
   INSERT INTO desttable (pkfield, field1, field2 ...)
   SELECT field1, field2
   FROM sourcetable
   ```

   `sourcetable` can also be a table in a different database like so:

   ```
   INSERT INTO desttable (pkfield, field1, field2 ...)
   SELECT field1, field2
   FROM sourcetable IN path\to\mdb
   ```

   so for each path you could build the SQL statemnt by substituting the appropriate path each time.
4. If you want to iterate over all the mdb files in a particular folder, you can use the `EnumerateFiles` method of the `Directory` class, in the `System.IO` namespace. Alternatively, you can open up a dialog box with the `OpenFileDialog` in the `Windows.Forms` namespace.
5. Once you've figured out what kind of UI you want to see, it should be trivial to bind to this data.

Comment: Is this sufficient? Or do you need more detail about binding to the UI? If it's sufficient, please mark the question as answered, by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: the qurey of insert works great in MS-ACCESS but didn't work in c# i display the query in textbox in c# and copy the query in ms-access and works

Comment: Please update your question with the C# code that didn't work.